How to turn off prefixing element keys
Using Drupal 10 in a university setting. I want to stop the prefixing of elements and just use the element name. There appears to be an issue with prefixed elements in an email. For example:
.
Name : [webform_submission:values:name]
EMail : [webform_submission:values:email]
Phone : [webform_submission:values:phone]
Campus : [webform_submission:values:campus]
Department : [webform_submission:values:your_contact_information_02_email]
Building : [webform_submission:values:your_contact_information_02_phone] - Room Number : [webform_submission:values:room_number]
Description : [webform_submission:values:description]
Department and Building does not show the value, it sees them as text literals. All fields without prefixing do should the values. What I don't understand is why some elements prefixed while other do not. I did not edit the keys.
And all the fields are checked in "Included email values/markup"
I'm unable to edit source, feature apparently turned off.
I just want to turn off all prefixing of keys.
Much Thanks

This question needs to define "prefixing of elements" and "prefixing of keys" as I for one don't understand what you mean by them. Additionally, this question should include some information as to what the form design is, because we don't know it. Finally, the question needs to demonstrate, literally, what the undesirable behavior is. Then it may be ready to accept answers.

[webform_submission:values:email] and similar patterns are tokens.  These tokens are used in the Webform module to add user-submitted form values to notifications. They are not "prefixed"; the webform_submission is an address, similar to how example.com in www.example.com/email is an address.  You can't remove this webform_submission because then the Webform module won't be able to find the right value to replace the token with.

Department and Building does not show the value, it sees them as text
literals.

If the token pattern is invalid, it will not be replaced.
If the token pattern is valid but there is no value, it will be blank.
Since you're seeing the text literal, it means this token is incorrect.  You need to find the correct token for the value you want to replace and use that in the form.
